# Returning traceparent header from ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, opentracing

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API exposed from my service. I want to enable tracing in this service for troubleshooting.

If the incoming request has `traceparent` header I will add a `span` to it and use. If the incoming request doesn't have `traceparent`, I will generate a new trace and use it.

Now, I want to return this `traceparent` header in the response. The current solution I have come up is to write a middleware which will inject the `traceparent` header into the `HttpContext`.

Does .NET Core provide an easier way to do this instead of me manually adding this header in the response?

Comment: Based on my opinion, the middleware is the right way, if you don't want it, filter could be also a right way. all in all, there is no easy way to achieve this.

Comment: BTW, the reader name being considered in the response is  'traceresponse', not 'traceparent' which is the request header. https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/#traceresponse-header